# How to specify per application properties in JBoss configuration?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly

I have a web application in which I want to inject property values (like external server hostname and password - environment dependent). I want to specify the values in the Wildfly configuration.

I thought I will specify simple JNDI binding in the *urn:jboss:domain:naming* subsystem, and inject property using `@Resource` annotation, like:

```
@Resource(name = "java:app/rabbit.login")
private String login;
```

But in naming subsystem I cannot specify an application-scoped JNDI binding (it is necessary due to security reasons).

How can I specify properties (using JDNI, properties, etc.) in the Wildfly configuration accessible only for specific application?

Answer (score 0):

If you want that your properties are accessible only at application level just use any startup component (e.g. @Singleton @Startup) and read the properties from a File. Another option is packaging the property in a module, install the module on the application server and include a dependency to the module in your application.
See this [wiki](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HowToPutAnExternalFileInTheClasspath):

Comment: First option doesn't meets my requirements, because I want to separate configuration from application (in this solution I would need to put .properties file into my jar, but I would like to have this in server configuration). Second option is not secure enougth, beacause any application deployed can read all properties.